# Activator "404 - Failed to load resource:..." and to locate the bower components

Tags: angularjs, playframework, http-status-code-404, bower

I've build a small webapp in angularjs and is now about to make use of the play framework for my backend. However, now after installing Play (activator) when I try to start the web service I keep getting these error messages about that my bower components are missing (404 - not found)

```
GET http://localhost:9000/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css
GET http://localhost:9000/bower_components/bootstrap-social/bootstrap-social.css 
GET http://localhost:9000/bower_components/ngDialog/css/ngDialog.css  
...
```

I'm guessing that it is just a minor error here but can't understand what it might be.

Comment: What is the location of bower_components folder? Share your routes file. Only then we will be able to say what is wrong. In otherwise your url is not properly framed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bower_components` is the folder created by bower itself. 
If you didn't use bower to install/download the components that you need, you won't have that folder.

Your example shows that bootstrap was installed with bower. Did you copy an enxample?

If you have bower running on your maschine just run `bower install bootstrap` and it will fetch and download the needed files for you.

If you don't have bower installed here is what you need to do.

1. Install nodeJS
2. run `npm install bower`
3. run `bower install bootstrap`

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by just re-installing bower with:

```
bower install
```